# Configuring nginx for a subdirectory without using a symlink

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, web-server, php-fpm

I've been trying to set up phpmyadmin on my nginx server using [this outdated tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) from DigitalOcean.  The idea is to have the following configuration:

`http(s)://example.com` => `/usr/share/nginx/html`

`http(s)://example.com/phpmyadmin` => `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`

The tutorial's "solution" is to just create a symlink in `/usr/share/nginx/html` that points to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.  This is the same approach used in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/488462/configuring-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-fedora-17-for-access-at-localhost-phpmyadmin).  Unfortunately, this creates some [other problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/433785/nginx-phpmyadmin-redirecting-to-instead-of-phpmyadmin-upon-login) which I won't go into here.

It seems to me that I should be able to use individual `location` blocks to control this behavior.  I've tried the approach suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/218818/nginx-projects-in-subfolders):

```
server {
        listen 80 default;

        server_name localhost;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
            root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        }

        location ~ /phpmyadmin/.+\.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

I can still reach nginx's default page at `http://example.com`, and even execute PHP scripts via URLs such as `http://example.com/info.php`.  Unfortunately, whenever I try to visit any `http://example.com/*` URL, I get a 404 error.

How should I configure this properly?  I'm running PHP7.0 with PHP-FPM on a Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some suggestions below. DISCLAIMER: It has not been tested.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `root` statement was wrong, unless phpmyadmin is below `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`.

You can nest the `PHP` location blocks, and use the `^~` modifier, which looks tidier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

I have added a few [`try_files` statements](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), in accordance with [best practice](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/). Also, a `location /` block to handle *normal* URIs.

You may want to change some of those `=404` codes into default actions.

Comment: I prefer using `alias` directives in `location` blocks, then it is not so easy to get confused when the URI is appended to the end of the directory.

Comment: That's fine, but be aware that they are more expensive.